# How to obtain the view showing and reload the menu table while using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, slide

I am using https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController to develop my apps. I have two questions while I building my apps.

1. In the SidebarViewController.m, which is came from the tutorial here http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/, 
   I edited the method
   `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

   where I want to disable specific menu button on specific view by setting `cell.userInteractionEnabled` property, for example when I'm in the vc1, I disable the segue that will persent vc1. By this mean, I want to find out the current viewcontroller's restorationIdentifier in order to decide the selection, but I can't find any method to get the current viewController showing, I've try 
       `self.revealViewController.frontViewController.presentedViewController.restorationIdentifier`   `self.revealViewController.frontViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:`

   which is all wrong.

2.Besides the segue function to change view, my apps support manually change view, suppose I press some button on vc1, the apps will push vc2. By this mean, the SidebarViewController.m method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

wont call again, so that the setting previously wont apply to the new vc2. I tried `[tableview reload]` , but still dont work.

Thanks for everyone's great help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but I use this code to localise my sliding menu if language settings are changed (my localisation is inside the App):

Inside `SWRevealViewController.m`.

```
    - (void (^)(void))_rearViewDeploymentForNewFrontViewPosition:(FrontViewPosition)newPosition

...

        if ([_rearViewController isKindOfClass:([tvcMenu class])])
        {
            [((tvcMenu*)_rearViewController).tvMenu reloadData];
        }

        return completion;
```